# Java: Fixing Imports

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, import

I am using VSCode and at the moment my model is stored in src/main/java/model. My problem is that when importing, I need to type import src.main.java.model.* which I am strongly against for obvious reasons.

How do I make it so I only have to type import java.model.* or model.*?
(I have already tried adding the folder to source path but it is already included, as the entire directory is included as a source path.)

EDIT: The solution is gimmicky, but the solution was to move a level higher to remove the entire repository as a source path, so I would be able to add just the model folder as a source path.

Comment: "which I am strongly against for obvious reasons." - please explain the obvious reasons

Comment: src/main is a build path, not exactly supposed to be part of package declaration. 

Imagine if every single import needed you to type the full directory for no reason
import src.main.java.lib.discord.core.nodeconnector. It'd be even worse if the directory went deeper

Comment: Definitely this project is not set up correctly in VS Code. It should know that src/main/java is (one of the items in) your classpath, or that this is a maven or gradle or whatever project, and assume the default structure. Take a look at how you created or imported the project in VS Code. Sorry, I don't use it for Java. Your package should definitely be `model.Etc`, not `java.model.Etc`.

Comment: You said "the entire directory is included as a source path". That sounds wrong to me. Try removing the base directory as a source path, and *only* adding `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` as source paths.

Comment: @DavidConrad That's what I would think to and yet it says the directory isn't in any source path.

Comment: "I need to type import `src.main.java.model.*`": no you don't. You need to import the actual package names that are in your .java files. `src, main`, and `java` are not part of that.

Comment: @user207421 I fixed the issue but yes, I do. I did attempt to import the actual package name and the problem was the actual package name also included src.main.java.

Answer (score 0):

If your project does not use aby build tools(Maven, Gradle), you can trigger the command `Java: Configure Classpath`, and set the folder `src/main/java` as a source root.